# Opening OrientDB Database in Eclipse Maven project throws errors

Tags: java, eclipse, orientdb

The error I am getting is as follows:

> ```
>     " Aug 25, 2015 1:47:41 PM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
> INFO: OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=4,161MB (heap=1,776MB os=7,985MB disk=416,444MB)
> Aug 25, 2015 1:47:41 PM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
> WARNING: segment file 'database.ocf' was not closed correctly last time
> Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.common.exception.OException: Error on creation
> ```
>
> of shared resource
>         at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OSharedContainerImpl.getResource(OSharedContainerImpl.java:55)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault.init(OMetadataDefault.java:175)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault.load(OMetadataDefault.java:77)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.initAtFirstOpen(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2633)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:254)
>         at arss.db.main(db.java:17)
>       Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ORecordNotFoundException:
>   The record with id '#0:1' not found
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.reload(ORecordAbstract.java:266)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.reload(ODocument.java:665)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.type.ODocumentWrapper.reload(ODocumentWrapper.java:91)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.type.ODocumentWrapperNoClass.reload(ODocumentWrapperNoClass.java:73)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.load(OSchemaShared.java:786)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault$1.call(OMetadataDefault.java:180)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault$1.call(OMetadataDefault.java:175)
>         at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OSharedContainerImpl.getResource(OSharedContainerImpl.java:53)
>         ... 5 more
>       Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error
>   on retrieving record #0:1 (cluster: internal)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1605)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.loadRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:80)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.reload(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1453)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.reload(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:117)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.reload(ORecordAbstract.java:260)
>         ... 12 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.orientechnologies.common.concur.lock.ONewLockManager.tryAcquireSharedLock(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Z
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.acquireReadLock(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1301)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionAbstract.lockRecord(OTransactionAbstract.java:120)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId.lock(ORecordId.java:282)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.lockRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1784)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.readRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1424)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.readRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:697)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1572)
>         ... 16 more"

The code that I use is:

```
package arss;

import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.config.OGlobalConfiguration;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.ORecordSerializerFactory;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinary;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV;



public class db {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("plocal:C:/AR/AR/Newfolder/orientdb-community-2.0.3_S/databases/GratefulDeadConcerts").open("admin", "admin");



            try {

                    // CREATE A NEW DOCUMENT AND FILL IT
                    ODocument doc = new ODocument("Person");

                    doc.field( "name", "Luke" );
                    doc.field( "surname", "Skywalker" );
                    doc.field( "city", new ODocument("City").field("name","Rome").field("country", "Italy") );

                    // SAVE THE DOCUMENT
                    doc.save();

                    db.close();

                } finally {

                  db.close();

                }



            }

        }"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not sure if you need .flush with ODocuments, you should look that up. (or if save is an equivalent and its okay)
2. from those two errors lines:

   WARNING: segment file 'database.ocf' was not closed correctly last time

and

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1572) ... 16 more"
```

I think it has something to do with the database.ocf file itself. dont know if this helps, but try opening it manually, preferable with/without admin and close it again. ("Have you tried turning it off and on again?")

If there is still an erorr, check if it is a different one.

Comment: different error I mean - possible that eclipse f***ed it up closing the file the last time you executed the code and now it shows something different than in the beginning

Comment: thanks! it was database issue.. i>ve fixed it @Cribber